# SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have the following code that uses SharePoint SP jQuery to get autocomplete from a list which works perfect.

However:

1. How can I include more columns in the code?
2. It would not accept some of the column names such as [User ID] or [User Email/Name].

I'm thinking because of the / or the space in the column name. How can I eliminate that in the code instead of changing the column name in SharePoint list?

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitename/JQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitename/JQuery/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
sourceList: "MyListName",
sourceColumn: "User",
columnName: "User",
numChars: 2,
ignoreCase: true,
slideDownSpeed: 100,
debug: true
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Space should not be an issue.

Note that, `sourceColumn` is a static name.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPAutocomplete

> StaticName
>
> StaticName (as opposed to DisplayName) means the underlying column
>   name, e.g., Region_x0020_Name. This is also sometimes called the
>   'internal name' for the column. The DisplayName would be Region Name,
>   i.e., the name of the column which is shown on forms and as the header
>   in list views. Probably the easiest way to determine the StaticName if
>   you don't know it is to go to List Settings and click on the column
>   name link. When you get to the column properties page, check the URL.
>   It will end in something like this:
>   /*layouts/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B37920121%2D19B2%2D4C77%2D92FF%2D8B3E07853114%7D&Field=Potential%5Fx0020%5FValue
>   The StaticName is the value for the Field parameter at the end. This
>   is a little tricky because some of the characters are further encoded.
>   Any occurrences of '%5F' need to be replaced with an underscore '*'.
>   Examples:
>
> Potential%5Fx0020%5FValue -> Potential_x0020_Value
>   Child%5Fx0020%5FSite%5Fx0020%5FName -> Child_x0020_Site_x0020_Name
>
> DisplayName
>
> DisplayName (as opposed to StaticName) means the name of the column
>   which is shown on forms and as the header in list views, e.g., Region
>   Name. The StaticName would be Region_x0020_Name, i.e., the underlying
>   column name.